# Unable to subscribe to Pushpad Safari notifications

Tags: safari, web-push, pushpad

I'm using the Pushpad.xyz library and got my Chrome notifications to work. On Firefox, I call pushpad('unsupported', callbackFunction) and the callbackFunction successfully executes (another bug that I am figuring out separately since Firefox should be supported).  However, I am unable to get Safari notifications to work. I entered my Apple developer's certificates as requested in https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_pro_requirements.

```
pushpad('init', projectID);
pushpad('uid', signature);
pushpad('subscribe', function(isSubscribed) { alert(isSubscribed); });

pushpad('unsupported', function() { alert('Unsupported browser'); });
```

On Safari, I don't get the callback to unsupported and the docs say that Safari is supported. Why does it say that the user (me) has blocked notifications for this website? The callback to "status" always returns false. Is there a way to verify that I set up my Apple certificate correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Safari is definitely related to the download of the push package and its signature.

When `pushpad('subscribe')` is invoked Safari tries to download a "push package" from Pushpad servers and verifies its integrity and signature. If an error occurs (e.g. the signature verification fails) then the user is not even asked for permission and permission is not `granted` (its value remains `default`).

So you see that strange message that says that the user has not granted permission. Actually in your case it's not the user who is blocking the notifications: it's Safari who refuses to subscribe to push notifications because the push package is invalid.

Please try to generate again and **fix the APNS private key and APNS certificate in your sender's settings on Pushpad**. This should solve the issue.

Make sure to follow exactly the steps described here for APNS:
https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_pro_requirements

**If you are testing your website locally** make sure to follow the instructions as described in the ["Working Locally" section](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_pro_getting_started):

- pass the `hostname` option to `init`
- make sure that the address is exactly http://localhost (if you use for example http://127.0.0.1 Safari won't work locally)